# Convert Date String In Excel to SQL datetime

Tags: sql, excel, datetime

I have searched for an answer to this, but have only ever found people wanting to do the reverse.

We have a reporting tool called JetReports, which is an Excel addin.

I am querying a database containing information about who has entered/left our building, and want to filter by date/time.

The filters in JetReports are literal, so if I filter the `EventTime` using a value of `20/09/2013 13:27`, it searches for exactly that. The SQL database in question is storing this as a `DATETIME` value, which when converted is in fact `41172.5604167`

I don't think my users will like having convert their dates to this format before running the report, so I would like to do it for them within Excel.

Is there some way I could convert a date in the format of `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` to the SQL `DATETIME` format?

Answer (score 2):

It does not say in your question if you are using SQL Server or not. If so, did you try to use [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) on the server side?

```
DECLARE @d nvarchar(100)
SET @d = N'30/10/2013 20:40'

SELECT CONVERT(smalldatetime, @d, 103) AS [DateTime]
```

Comment: It is a SQL Server 2008 R2, but we only have read only access to the database. JetReports does query using normal SQL commands, but we do not get to manipulate those commands directly, only through custom Excel functions.

Answer (score 1):

The date serial numbers in excel are exactly the same, it should just be a matter of formatting, e.g. if you have `20/09/2013 13:27` and simply re-format as number with 7 decimal places then you should see `41172.5604167` as required

If the re-formatting doesn't change the value then your date/time is text formatted. Try converting to numeric by using

`Data > Text to columns > Finish`

Comment: What JetReports does, is create a sheet called "Options" with a field that is updated by the user when the report runs. If the user changes the date, JetReports will set that field to ="20/09/2013 13:27" . Changing the cell format does not change how it displays, meaning I can't get it converted to a number. Any other change will be undone when the report is run again.